# Finding volume of the solid of revolution?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, rotations, volume

Can anyone help me with finding the volume of a solid of revolution of f(x) about the x axis for the interval [1,6].  It's supposed to be able to be done without needing calculus but I am having trouble figuring it out.

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1  &  1 \leq x< 2\\ 
1/2 &  2 \leq x< 3\\ 
. &          .\\ 
. &          .\\
1/n &  n\leq x< n+1\\ 
\end{cases}$

I know the volume would be found like this $\pi$ $\int_{1}^{6}(f(x))^2dx$ but I am unsure about how to go about it with this function.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Well the function is constant in the five intervals $(1,2),(2,3),\cdots,(5,6)$ and the last contribution will for example be $\;\displaystyle\pi\int_{5}^{6}(1/5)^2\,dx$. Further I think like Fantini that $2$ should be $1/2$.

Comment: If that's the case then shouldn't it be $f(x) = 1/2$ for $2 \leq x < 3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x)$ is constant in $n$ intervals. Hence, $\int^b_a (f(x))^2dx=(f(x))^2(b-a)$. So, the volume is simply
$$\pi\left(1^2(2-1)+2^2(3-2)+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n^2}(n+1-n)\right)=\pi\left(1^2+2^2+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
Though I believe that the $2$ should actually be $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you I am starting to understand it now.  Could you explain how to find the surface area as well on this interval?